# SQL Update Query with dynamic input values and multiple WHERE condition in Node JS

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I'm trying to update the database using single SQL query with dynamic array input and multiple WHERE condition which is also dynamic as well. Tried various SQL queries and referred blogs, but couldn't able to find any query suiting my need.

StudentsTable will have 3 columns (studentID, Dept, contactNo, contactEmail)

Front-end application will call API with array (whose length can vary), then I've to update 'contactNo' and 'contactEmail' fields for StudentsTable with 'studentID + dept' in WHERE condition.

Example input:

```
[
{"studentId": 100, "dept": "CS", "phone": 123456789, "email":"a@gmail.com" },
{"studentId": 7810, "dept": "PS",  "phone": 434242424, "email":"b@gmail.com" },
{"studentId": 510, "dept": "EE", "phone": 849384983, "email":"vu@gmail.com" },
{"studentId": 980, "dept": "CS", "phone": 543535353, "email":"z@gmail.com" },
]
```

Tried below, but don't know how to make it dynamic without using forEach loop.

```
UPDATE StudentsTable 
SET contactNo = CASE 
    WHEN  student_id = 100 AND dept = "CS" THEN 123456789
    WHEN  student_id = 980 AND dept = "CS" THEN 543535353
    END
WHERE student_id IN (100, 980) AND dept IN "CS"
SET contactEmail = CASE 
    WHEN  student_id = 100 AND dept = "CS" THEN "a@gmail.com"
    WHEN  student_id = 980 AND dept = "CS" THEN "z@gmail.com"
    END
WHERE student_id IN (100, 980) AND dept IN "CS"
```

Comment: this sounds like code optimisation on stackoverflow this is offtopic.. Also working with json always pretty much requires a loop

Comment: you should leave out where clauses and use CASE WHEN clauses, then simply construct the query string using a loop.

Comment: to add to @NikosM comment. i believe javascript supported join (should be support by Node.js) method aswell to make a string from array attributes

Answer (score 1):

Can you try inserting your array in a temporary table(StudentsTableChanged for this example) and then update using join ?

Update query will be something similar to below

```
UPDATE 
    StudentsTable t1
SET 
    t1.contactNo = t2.contactNo,
    t1.contactEmail = t2.contactEmail
FROM 
    t1
    INNER JOIN StudentsTableChanged t2 ON t1.student_id = t2.student_id AND t1.dept = t2.dept
```